# Rails period inside of url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

I am having trouble getting rid of a period inside of my url. I've look up others solution to this problem but either of them were for the index action.

Here is what a url looks like

```
/shared_songs.32 #current url structure
/shared_songs/32 #would like this format
```

Here is what is inside of my routes.rb

```
  get 'shared_songs/:note_id' => "shared_songs#show" #works fine
  get 'shared_songs', to: "shared_songs#index", as: "shared_songs" #/shared_songs.32
```

Inside of my index.html.erb file I currently have

```
link_to song.name, shared_songs_path(song)
```

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Which action is /shared_songs/32 supposed to be going to?

Comment: when browsing the index action and clicking on a link_to link it should take you to the correct song, which it does but it adds a period to the url rather than a /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
link_to song.name, shared_songs_path(song)
```

Do:

```
link_to song.name, shared_song_path(song)
```

`song`, not `songs`

Comment: When doing so I receive the error `undefined method shared_song_path`

Comment: Add `as: :shared_song` to your first route

Comment: works as before as there is still a dot in the url. This is very strange

Comment: Do you have anything else in your routes.rb? Also, it is not fully clear to me, you want `shared_songs/32` be mapped to index or show action?

Comment: The above used to work only for the index action when using `resources :shared_songs, :only => [:index, :show]` but the show action did not work. I changed routes to match the url but the index action is the only one that does not seem to work and by work I'm referring to the link_to not working as it is including a period in the url.

Comment: Change it back to resources, the current way is much worse. Index action should not contain any number in url and you should not pass any params to the helper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59437/discussion-between-broisatse-and-yooku).

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because you are taking a url helper that doesn't have any dynamic segments (:id, :user_id etc.) in the path, but you're giving it a value anyway (song). Not knowing what else to do with it, rails uses that value as the format, which is why you end up with /shared_songs/32

`shared_song_path(song)` doesn't work because you don't current have a route called `shared_song`. As several of the comments say, by far the easiest way is to do

```
resources :shared_songs
```

This will give you a functioning `shared_songs_path` (for the index, doesn't expect any arguments_ and `shared_song_path` (requires a parameter). You'll have to change your controller slightly because the the id of the song will be in `params[:id]` instead of `params[:note_id]`

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you define your routes in a RESTful manner: something like `resources :shared_songs`. [As explained much more clearly in the Rails docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing:-the-rails-default), using the `resources` helper will automatically set up appropriate routes to the corresponding controller actions.